Writing the Lagrange of a Normal Distribution
I am watching this Youtube video on how to derive the Multivariate Normal Distribution using the Principle of Maximum Entropy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qsB8ElrCC4 @ 3:13).
Here, the Lagrange of this Optimization Problem is given:
$$
L = - \int p(x) \log p(x) \, dx - \alpha \left[ \int p(x) \, dx - 1 \right] - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i \cdot \int (x_i p(x) - \mu_i) \, dx
$$
$$
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \gamma_{ij} \cdot \int (x_i-\mu_i)(x_j-\mu_j) p(x) \, dx - \sigma_{ij}
$$
I am a bit confused as to how the Lagrange was formed for this problem.

I understand that this is the formula for entropy: $- \int p(x) \log p(x) \, dx$
I am confused about the Normalization Constant $ - \alpha \left[ \int p(x) \, dx - 1 \right] $ . I understand that $\alpha$ is a Lagrange Variable, and that integral of $p(x)$ over all possible values is 1, but then we subtract 1 and it again becomes 0. Why does  $ - \alpha \left[ \int p(x) \, dx - 1 \right] $ serve as a normalizing constant and why is it needed? Why is a normalization constant needed?
I understand that $x_i p(x)$ is the expected value of $x_i$ , and for some reason we want the difference between the expected value and the mean to be 0 (I am not sure why) as a constraint. Here, $\beta_i$ is a Lagrange Variable
Again, I think that $\gamma_{ij}$ is a Lagrange Variable. Here, it looks like we are taking the expected value of $(x_i - \mu_i) \cdot (x_j - \mu_j)$. Is $(x_i - \mu_i) \cdot (x_j - \mu_j)$ somehow an estimator of $\sigma_{ij}$?

Can someone please help me understand the logic behind how this Lagrange was formed?

See this related question

In setting up this Lagrangian, the function $\rho(x)$ is yet to be determined. As such, we need to specify all of the constraints that make it a valid probability distribution with the desired properties, and the standard way to introduce a constraint is by including a term $\lambda h(x)$ such that $h(x) = 0$ where the constraint holds.
So we then have:

$\alpha \left[\int \rho(x) dx - 1 \right]$ introduces a constraint that the integral over the whole probability space is 1, i.e. it is a probability density function.

$\beta_i \left[\int x_i \rho(x) dx - \mu_i\right]$ is a constraint that the expectation over $X_i$ is $\mu_i$.

$\gamma_{ij} \left[\int (x_i - \mu_i)(x_j - \mu_j) \rho(x) dx - \sigma_{ij} \right]$ is a constraint that the appropriate second moment is equal to $\sigma_{ij}$, i.e. it has the right variance structure.


